# Determine what quarter a day is in, represented with integers - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a search function that looks through days, but days are Integer Type and a quarter is 91 days long. I have a `currentDay`, and a loop looks for a condition on `searchDay`. `currentDay` is read in from a workbook, returns what quarter the search day is in.

Relative to `currentDay` I want to know if the `searchDay` is in the same quarter, next quarter, or after. I am able to determine if `searchDay` is in the same quarter as `currentDay` using `Mod` to determine when the cycle starts again.

```
Dim currentDay as Integer
Dim searchDay as Integer
Dim lengthOfSearch as Integer 

lengthOfSearch = 728 'Two years of searching

currentDay = 45

searchDay = 87 ' Same Quarter example
searchDay = 95 ' Next Quarter example
searchDay = 185 ' After example


For i = 1 to lengthOfSearch
   If (currentDay Mod 91) <= (searchDay Mod 91) then
       MsgBox "Current Quarter"

   Else If conditions then
       MsgBox "Next Quarter"

   Else MsgBox "After Next Quarter"
   End If
Next i
```

Can I just use:

```
(currentDay Mod 182) <= (searchDay Mod 182) then
```

***EDIT: I think my current quarter conditions are incorrect. If it was day 274 (Q4), and the search day was 380 (Q1 of next year), the condition would return, `TRUE`, (274 Mod 91 = 4) <= (300 Mod 91 = 30).

Comment: Are`CurrentDay` and `SearchDay` in same year always? Is `CurrentDay` always less than `SearchDay`? Why not just an UDF that returns the quarter number of a specific date?

Comment: `currentDay` and `searchDay` are not always in the same year, but I don't track years, just number of days. So 5 years would just be integer of 1820. `currentDay` is always less than `searchDay`. The search is a scheduling algorithm, that looks to add data to a collection, and I want to know if it was added this quarter, next, or after.

Comment: why don't you use `format(someDate,"Q")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, you seem to have made this more complicated than it needs to be.

Can you not simply work out the quarter for the search day and then subtract the quarter for the current day?

If quarters are ALWAYS 91 days as you have stated, this could be done with a simple formula:

```
=ROUNDUP( <SearchDay> /91,0)-ROUNDUP( <CurrentDay> /91,0)
```

This would result in 0 if they are in the same quarter, 1 if SearchDay is in the next quarter, and so on.

Have I miss-understood your question?

Comment: Using Worksheet.Function is slowing down the VBA code quite a bit. Is `Int(searchDay/91) + 1` going to achieve a similar operation?

Comment: Yes it would... However, you do not need the +1. It doesn't matter if you round up or down as long as you treat them both the same. Out of curiosity, why are you using VBA? In your example, there is no point in your FOR loop. As you are not using your i counter, it is just performing the exact same thing 1 to lengthOfSearch times.

Comment: Yes I am using VBA, and sorry the code is edited from the main module, which automatically advanced search day and current. It's a scheduling algorithm that looks for appointments.

Comment: No problem. I assumed that it was a simplified example. But your conversion to `Int(searchDay/91)-Int(currentDay/91)` should still do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following. I hope I understood correctly your needs.

```
Function calc(c As Integer, s As Integer, l As Integer) As Integer

    rem lenQ = l / 91

    crtQ = c / 91
    srcQ = s / 91

    calc = srcQ - crtQ

End Function


Sub doSmth()

    Rem expect 0
    MsgBox calc(45, 87, 728)

    Rem expect 1
    MsgBox calc(45, 95, 728)

    Rem expect 2
    MsgBox calc(45, 185, 728)

End Sub
```

Just be careful that a year is a tad longer than 4x91 days. Depending on your problem, this might prove to be an issue.